# What do these symbols mean? I'm trying to understand them to make an app

Tags: cryptography

What do the symbols `⊞` and `⊕` mean? I'm trying to understand them to make an app.

It's on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:XXTEA.png

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:XXTEA.png]

Comment: From the context it is obvious that the squared + is simply an addition.

Comment: There's some reference code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA#Reference_code), but the single letter variables are giving me a headache.  Why does crypto code always look evil to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know for a fact that ⊕ means XOR, or eXclusive OR. With the variables A and B, Normal OR will return true if

- A=true and b=false
- A=false and B=true
- A=true and B=true

XOR on the other hand returns true only if

- A=false and B=true
- A=true and B=false

---

I'm not too sure about ⊞ though. In Unicode its [under "SQUARED PLUS"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/229e/index.htm), but I don't know how that works in an algorithm

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old, but I'll answer the question anyway for future readers:

- `⊕` is the XOR function, where two identical bits produce `0`, and two different bits produce `1`.
- `⊞` is a modular addition function, where the modulus must be clearly defined in advance (such as `a ⊞ b = a + b mod 2^32`).
- `<<n` is the left logical bit-shift operator, shifted n-bits (not circular). Left shifting 1-bit would be equivalent to multiplying by 2.
- `>>n` in the signed right logical bit-shift operator, shifted n-bits (not circular). Right shifting 1-bit would be equivalent to dividing by 2 and taking the floor of the result.